# Problem with Rails 3 and MySQL related to JSON dependency in ActiveSupport

Tags: mysql, json, ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

I built my Rails 3 app using sqlite and now I'm trying to switch over to MySQL.

I created a new MySQL db, changed database.yml accordingly, and I added an older version of the mysql2 gem to my gemfile (`gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'`) which is supposed to [play nicer with Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467054/problem-with-mysql2-and-rails3-bundler/6048651#6048651).

I can start the dev server fine. When I visit a page, I get a `Mysql2::Error` (`Table 'twitter_quiz_development.users' doesn't exist`). Which is fine--I still need to add the schema to the new db. This is where I run into trouble:

`rake db:schema:load` returns [this nasty error](http://pastie.org/2011410).

The solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262616/ruby-1-9-2-blows-up-with-json-gem-dependency/4263063#4263063) did not work for me. `gem pristine --all` return [this](http://pastie.org/2011446).

I'm running Ubuntu 11 if that helps.

It appears that the error has to do with JSON but I have no idea how to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: What OS are you running? **Edit:** apologies, I noticed you've already mentioned that.

Comment: Jits and NFM, I'll implement your suggestions shortly. I really appreciate this...this one is killing me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue(s) you are experiencing could be due to 3 things:

- The version of Ruby you are using
- The use of the SystemTimer gem with Ruby 1.9
- The JSON gem

I've elaborated below...

The first thing I would suggest is to upgrade your version of Ruby 1.9. The latest stable is:

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909)
```

I would highly recommend using [Ruby Version Manager (RVM)](https://rvm.io) to install and manage Rubies.

In terms of using the JSON gem, have a look at:
http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/a/The-Json-Gem.htm

To quote:

> On Ruby 1.8.7, you'll need to install a gem. However, in Ruby 1.9.2, the json gem is bundled with the core Ruby distribution. So, if you're using 1.9.2, you're probably all set. If you're on 1.8.7, you'll need to install a gem.
>
> Before you install the JSON gem, first realize that this gem is distrubuted in two variants. Simply installing this gem with gem install json will install the C extension variant. This requires a C compiler to install, and may not be available or appropriate on all systems. Though if you can install this version, you should.
>
> If you can't install the C extension version, you should gem install json_pure instead. This is the same gem implemented in pure Ruby. It should run everywhere that Ruby code runs, on all platforms and on a variety of interpreters. However, it's considerably slower than the C extension version.

**Edit**:

Looks like you should avoid using the **SystemTimer** gem with Ruby 1.9. See this for more info: http://isitruby19.com/systemtimer

To quote a comment made on that page by Phillipe:

> I am the (co)-author of this gem. Short story : Using this gem in Ruby 1.9 is useless and does not make any sense!
>
> System Timer is trying to work around some limitation of the "green thread" model used in Ruby 1.8 (MRI). See http://ph7spot.com/musings/system-timer for more details.
>
> It is then *irrelevant in a Ruby 1.9* which abandoned the green thread model and embraced native threads (kind of since there is still a global interpreter lock).
>
> Cheers, 
>   - Philippe

Answer (score 1):

Your `gem pristine --all` looks like it errored out with the `SystemTimer` gem before it got to the `json` gem. Is that gem used in the Rails app in question?

Are you using RVM? If so, I'd manually remove the `SystemTimer` and `json` gems and their binaries (if any) from `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-whatever-version/` (in the `gem` and `bin` subdirectories).

Try to update to the latest version of the `JSON` gem (1.5.1) by adding this to your Gemfile:

```
gem "json", "1.5.1"
```

And then run `bundle install` to install `SystemTimer` and the later version of the `json` gem.