# I have broken my ruby installation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macports

I have recently installed MacPorts and been playing with a few things I do not understand (doh!). I am now not able to install any new gems. I have looked at this answer: [Why does Ruby 1.9.2 blow up with a JSON gem dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262616/ruby-1-9-2-blows-up-with-json-gem-dependency)

But I still cannot install it. here is what terminal spits back at me:

```
c028004:me richardjburton$ sudo gem install twitter_oauth
Fetching: twitter_oauth-0.4.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed twitter_oauth-0.4.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for twitter_oauth-0.4.3...
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard.rb:38: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0019 p:---- s:0074 b:0074 l:000073 d:000073 CFUNC  :callcc
c:0018 p:0080 s:0071 b:0071 l:0002e0 d:0002e0 TOP    /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard.rb:38
c:0017 p:---- s:0068 b:0068 l:000067 d:000067 FINISH
c:0016 p:---- s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 CFUNC  :require
c:0015 p:0053 s:0062 b:0062 l:001a78 d:001a78 METHOD /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
c:0014 p:0030 s:0055 b:0055 l:0026c8 d:0026c8 METHOD /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/rubygems/doc_manager.rb:5
c:0013 p:0080 s:0052 b:0052 l:000048 d:000048 METHOD /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/rubygems/doc_manager.rb:59
c:0012 p:0021 s:0049 b:0049 l:000af8 d:000af8 METHOD /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/doc_manager.rb:116
c:0011 p:0037 s:0046 b:0046 l:001bb0 d:000ec0 BLOCK  /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:148
c:0010 p:---- s:0043 b:0043 l:000042 d:000042 FINISH
c:0009 p:---- s:0041 b:0041 l:000040 d:000040 CFUNC  :each
c:0008 p:0200 s:0038 b:0038 l:001bb0 d:001bb0 METHOD /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:147
c:0007 p:0076 s:0032 b:0032 l:000f30 d:000f30 METHOD /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command.rb:278
c:0006 p:0193 s:0028 b:0028 l:000fb0 d:000fb0 METHOD /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:147
c:0005 p:0013 s:0022 b:0022 l:001028 d:001028 METHOD /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:117
c:0004 p:0178 s:0017 b:0017 l:0010b0 d:0010b0 METHOD /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:65
c:0003 p:0267 s:0009 b:0009 l:0004e8 d:001d60 EVAL   /Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem:25
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0004e8 d:0004e8 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem:25:in `<main>'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:65:in `run'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:117:in `run'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command_manager.rb:147:in `process_args'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/command.rb:278:in `invoke'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:147:in `execute'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:147:in `each'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:148:in `block in execute'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/doc_manager.rb:116:in `generate_ri'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/rubygems/doc_manager.rb:59:in `install_ri_yard'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard/rubygems/doc_manager.rb:5:in `load_yardoc'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/richardjburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/yard-0.7.3/lib/yard.rb:38:in `callcc'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001097834ae rb_vm_bugreport + 110
1   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001096774c3 report_bug + 259
2   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000109677631 rb_bug + 161
3   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000109719f42 sigbus + 18
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff91a97cfa _sigtramp + 26
5   ???                                 0x00007fff6924313e 0x0 + 140734957367614

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

As always, any help would be be amazing.

Comment: Really lame comment here, but have you tried removing RVM completely and then installing everything again? When I have these crazy issues with rubies/crashing/whatever this always works.

Comment: Not related, but when using `rvm`, there's no reason to `sudo` the installs.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your gem installed succeeded, but failed at generating RI document. If you still want to use macport ,you can try install with --no-ri to skip it. It maybe OK for you.

Another, please try to uninstall the ruby with macport, and only use rvm. Maybe you need to try to reinstall rvm too.

Comment: considering the `.rvm` in the path, it would appear `rvm` is already being used.

Comment: I am still having major problems. So annoying.