# Ruby messes up when trying to do rake db:create with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have just installed postgresql, because I want to put my apps onto heroku. When trying to set up a new rails app using pq, once I rake db:create and I get the following error message, I have no clue what it means, or what to do.

Here's the error message that I'm receiving.

```
new-host-2:scheduleScraper rickmasta$ rake db:create:all
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `connect'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:144:in `rescue in create_database'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:85:in `create_database'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:52:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:184:in `local_database?'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:38:in `each_value'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"scheduleScraper_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"scheduleScraper", "password"=>nil}
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `connect'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:144:in `rescue in create_database'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:85:in `create_database'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:52:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:184:in `local_database?'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:38:in `each_value'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"scheduleScraper_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"scheduleScraper", "password"=>nil}
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `initialize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `connect'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:324:in `initialize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:144:in `rescue in create_database'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:85:in `create_database'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:52:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:184:in `local_database?'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:38:in `each_value'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/rickmasta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"scheduleScraper_production", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"scheduleScraper", "password"=>nil}
```

Comment: I would venture a guess that your installation of postgresql isn't in pristine shape. Have you tried this? http://postgresapp.com/ Also, you can perfectly run different databases in development and production if you install the right gems under the right environments in your Gemfile. But that's not such a good idea, so let's forget about it.

Comment: Ok, I've uninstalled the postgresql that I installed through brew. For some reason I had two versions installed. I'll try this application. Thank you!

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262616/ruby-1-9-2-blows-up-with-json-gem-dependency), it seems like you can end up with problems with the JSON parser, meaning this might not be your Postgres installation's fault.

Comment: Yup, uninstalling and installing the postgresapp did not help, having the same error.

Comment: i see a lot of json error messages. consider trying `gem update json` or something like that

Comment: What version of the pg gem are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue when installing PostgreSQL with brew on Mountain Lion.  Postgres is putting the socket file in a different directory, `/var/pgsql_socket_alt`, then where psql, createdb, Rails, etc. know where to look for it.  You need to change where the socket file goes via the postgres.conf file.  See [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/1mni7w) on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed postgres, but is it running?

I got almost identical errors after a reboot of my machine, because I didn't remember to (re)launch the postgres application locally.  After I launched the PostGres application again, everything worked without a problem.

These were my errors:

```
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
    from /Users/gregorysmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1216:in `new'
etc, etc. ........
```